# How to output multiple frames from GLSL postprocessing shader?

Tags: glsl, shader, post-processing

Can i use multiple ouptuts from postprocessing shader in GLSL?

I'm using Reshade with Super Depth 3D.
I added there sequential frame 3D output (for 120Hz monitor).
I need to rewrite part of it to allow 60FPS games display in 3D.

```
PSEUDOCODE:
Right now it is working only when game hit stable 120FPS with provided algorithm:
for each frame:
    if frame is even:
      generate left eye image
    else:
      generate right eye image

I have to change this to following one (so game can be played in 60FPS):
for each frame:
  generate left eye image AND right eye image
```

Sequence of frames before shader:
ABCDEF

After shader:
AABBCCDDEEFF

### EDIT

Apparently Reshade not allows to inject any new frame via shaders, because it is only appending information to already rendered frame.

So is this frame insertion possible via other software? (e.g. ENB)
Is there any software implementation of black frame insertion for DirectX/OpenGL games?
I'm assuming it have to get stream of 60FPS and output 120FPS.

Comment: A [Fragment Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader) can render to multiple render targets (e.g. textures).

Comment: But how to put these textures as frames in GPU buffer so they will be displayed as new frames? In shader input there is one frame and in output there should be 2 frames that have to be displayed one after one in sequence.

Comment: So why do you want to generate the the images for 2 eyes at once? Anyway you've to render the 2 images to a framebuffer with 2 color channels, where a texture is attached to each. Then the textures can be rendered to the default buffer, one in each frame. See [LearnOpenGL - Deferred Shading](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Deferred-Shading). (This question seems to be to broad)

Comment: I want to generate images for 2 eyes at once from one frame, because it's allows to play game with stable 60FPS and display it in 120FPS for 3D (60 frames for left eye, 60 frames for right eye, in sequence LRLR...). Frame will be simply copied and parallax effect will be applied (based on depth buffer).

I looked into page that you provided and i still can't get how this allow me to create 2 frames from one. AFAIK deferred shading uses MRT which still produces only 1 frame as output (combining G-Buffer textures).

Comment: Of course it can produce 2 images at once. But you've to use a different technique. Use a framebuffer with [Layered Images](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Layered_Images) (2 layers  in your case). The different view for the eyes and the layer can be set in a [Geometry Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Geometry_Shader) (see [Layered rendering](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Layered_rendering))

Comment: Reshade cannot use geometry shaders. It only allows for post-processing and surface pixel shaders. That is why i asked if post-processing shader allows to do that thing.

Comment: Render the scene to a texture and a depth buffer once (render to a framebuffer). Apply the parallax effect to the texture, twice.

Comment: If i understand it correctly then i should:
- create FBO and bind it,
- attach color and depth buffer,
- render texture to this FBO (via RTT),
- bind the native window FrameBuffer,
- apply parallax effect to the texture (twice - once for each eye),
- render texture to screen with a pixel shader twice.

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: I'll try that in the evening when i back home and give response if it works :) Thanks for help!